# Не могу найти ошибку в синтаксисе в SQL?

Tags: php, sql

Я в этом новичок, не могу понять, где ошибка.

> **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group, password, email) VALUES ( NULL, NULL, NULL, ' at line 2**

Вот это не полный код.

```
$result2 = "
    INSERT INTO register 
      (id, family_name, first_name, middle_name, year, faculty, direction, group, password, email)
    VALUES ( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '$year', '$faculty', '$direction', '$group', NULL, NULL)";
```

Comment: `group` в обратные кавычки заверните. и почитайте про передачу параметров в запрос

Comment: это ключевое слово используемое самим мускулом, поэтому ругается.